# Let $f(z)=z^2\bar{z}^3$. Calculate $f_z(z)$ and $f_\bar{z}(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z^2\bar{z}^3$. Calculate $f_z(z)$ and $f_\bar{z}(z)$.

I'm just wondering what the techniques are to solve this. Should I use the definition ? Or the product rule ? How this product rule works with $\bar{z}$ ?

Comment: Oh wait. Can't I just use $(z\bar{z})^2\bar{z}=|z|^4\bar{z}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $f_z(z)$?

Comment: @Awesome http://i.snag.gy/Y5yVy.jpg

Comment: I guess I will just go...

Comment: Differential of $\;f\;$ wrt to $\;z\;$, @Awesome...what else?

Comment: Why the downvote ? @Awesome

Comment: Not me... Let me upvote you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$ work just like partial derivatives where you treat $z$ and $\overline{z}$ as independent variables.  In other words, if $f(x,y)=x^2y^3$,  would know how to take the partial derivatives?  Same result in the complex case.

Comment: I don't think so. Read comment in deleted answer.

Comment: I cannot read a comment in a deleted answer, but I am quite sure of my own answer.